# "Unable to parse URL" exception after SOAP request

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I'm trying to use a soap service with php, but it seems that the request format that php creates couldn't be interpreted by the service. Simple example I have so far:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$client = new SoapClient('http://publicbetawebservices.hotel.de/V2_8/FreeHotelSearchWebService.svc?WSDL',array("trace"=>1));

try {
  $response = $client->GetWebservicesVersion();
} catch(Exception $e){ 
  print_r($e);
}
```

Output:

```
SoapFault Object
(
    [message:protected] => Unable to parse URL
    [string:Exception:private] =>
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /var/www/test.php
    [line:protected] => 6
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [function] => __doRequest
                    [class] => SoapClient
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://webservices.hotel.de/V2_8/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetWebservicesVersion/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

                            [1] =>
                            [2] => http://webservices.hotel.de/V2_8/IBaseService/GetWebservicesVersion
                            [3] => 1
                            [4] => 0
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/test.php
                    [line] => 6
                    [function] => __call
                    [class] => SoapClient
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => GetWebservicesVersion
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/test.php
                    [line] => 6
                    [function] => GetWebservicesVersion
                    [class] => SoapClient
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] =>
    [faultstring] => Unable to parse URL
    [faultcode] => HTTP
)
```

The resulting request xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://webservices.hotel.de/V2_8/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:GetWebservicesVersion />
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But as of the documentation of the webservice, it is expecting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
 <GetWebservicesVersion xmlns="http://webservices.hotel.de/V2_8/"/>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Is there a way to get the request xml to the expected format?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your resulting request is OK (equivalent to expected request from documentation). Problem is there is no endpoint address specified in wsdl `http://publicbetawebservices.hotel.de/V2_8/FreeHotelSearchWebService.svc?WSDL`. So SoapClient does not know URL where to post the request and you get error `Unable to parse URL`. You have to specify endpoint URL manually in code. For SoapClient this should work:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://publicbetawebservices.hotel.de/V2_8/FreeHotelSearchWebService.svc?WSDL',array("trace"=>1));
$client->__setLocation('http://publicbetawebservices.hotel.de/V2_8/FreeHotelSearchWebService.svc');
```

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588852/exception-javax-xml-ws-webserviceexception-unsupported-endpoint-address-tryin) also.

Answer (score 1):

Request was successfully processed.

```
try {

    if(setEndpoint('changeEndpoint')){
        $newLocation = $client->__setLocation(setEndpoint(' https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services')); // Please set url fedex email response
    }
    /* echo "<pre>";
     Print_r($request); */

    $response = $client ->track($request);
}
```